# Can user change ID of an element?

Tags: html, security

So as the title says I'm curious, can user change the ID of an element through browser? I have a list of inputs - checkboxes, when you click on one of them ajax takes ID of that element and uses it to get data from database, so basically what I'm thinking is that if it is somehow possible to change the ID of the element my database wouldn't be secured. If that's possible, how I should protect it?

Okay, So I get the idea that it wouldn't be secured, If I'd use this way:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");

$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["usuario"]);
$clave = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["clave"]);

$sql='  SELECT * FROM usuarios 
        WHERE username="'.$usuario.'" 
        AND pass="'.$clave.'"
     ';

$mysqli->query($sql);

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

would it be enough, or there aren't actually safe enough way to protect data?

Comment: Yes, they can. Trivially. Never trust what the browser submits; always check that they have permissions to act on whatever parameters they are submitting.

Comment: Check [OWASP Top Ten A7](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A7-Missing_Function_Level_Access_Control)

Comment: **PLEASE** do not store passwords in plain text...

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this would be a security hole. The ID attributes could indeed be changed via the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can change it or just make while request faked and you won't tell the difference. Rule of thumb here is **NEVER** trust any data that comes from user. It means - **always** validate, sanitize data on server-side, and always assume data that comes in request are there to fool/trick/hack you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The user can do anything they like to the DOM once it is in their browser.

They can also execute any JS they like there.

You're worrying about the problem in the wrong place though. Your control ends at the edge of the webserver. Clients can make any HTTP request they like to it and include any id value they want.  You need to address security there and not in the browser.

If you want to secure your database then you need to either allow no HTTP request to lead to the secret data being released / changed or you need to write server side rules that limit which HTTP requests can change them.

Typically this would involve Knowing Who The Request Comes From (Authentication) and Knowing Who Can Access Which IDs (Authorization).

A simple approach would be to keep a database that has a users table (including hashed passwords), a "things" table, and an ownership table (which has a column of user ids and a column of thing ids). If the request doesn't include a username and password you can cross reference from the thing id across the ownership table - return an error message instead of what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I thouht when a Device is pointed on the card off maybe Google there should be a change iff you can get into the Device with Smart switch or just an App wich can crack the IP,but i am Not sure.
Iff then you need the IP number and change it at the Place where it is shown and over the Sensor(Radiologie)it could be possible...cu.pp Oracle Legal Notices
Copyright Notice
Copyright © 1994-2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Trademark Notice
Oracle and Java are registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Intel and Intel Xeon are trademarks or registered trademarks of Intel Corporation. All SPARC trademarks are used under license and are trademarks or registered trademarks of SPARC International, Inc. AMD, Opteron, the AMD logo, and the AMD Opteron logo are trademarks or registered trademarks of Advanced Micro Devices. UNIX is a registered trademark of The Open Group.

License Restrictions Warranty/Consequential Damages Disclaimer
This software and related documentation are provided under a license agreement containing restrictions on use and disclosure and are protected by intellectual property laws. Except as expressly permitted in your license agreement or allowed by law, you may not use, copy, reproduce, translate, broadcast, modify, license, transmit, distribute, exhibit, perform, publish, or display any part, in any form, or by any means. Reverse engineering, disassembly, or decompilation of this software, unless required by law for interoperability, is prohibited.

Warranty Disclaimer
The information contained herein is subject to change without notice and is not warranted to be error-free. If you find any errors, please report them to us in writing.

Restricted Rights Notice
If this is software or related documentation that is delivered to the U.S. Government or anyone licensing it on behalf of the U.S. Government, the following notice is applicable:

U.S. GOVERNMENT RIGHTS Programs, software, databases, and related documentation and technical data delivered to U.S. Government customers are "commercial computer software" or "commercial technical data" pursuant to the applicable Federal Acquisition Regulation and agency-specific supplemental regulations. As such, the use, duplication, disclosure, modification, and adaptation shall be subject to the restrictions and license terms set forth in the applicable Government contract, and, to the extent applicable by the terms of the Government contract, the additional rights set forth in FAR 52.227-19, Commercial Computer Software License (December 2007). Oracle America, Inc., 500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood City, CA 94065.

Hazardous Applications Notice
This software or hardware is developed for general use in a variety of information management applications. It is not developed or intended for use in any inherently dangerous applications, including applications that may create a risk of personal injury. If you use this software or hardware in dangerous applications, then you shall be responsible to take all appropriate fail-safe, backup, redundancy, and other measures to ensure its safe use. Oracle Corporation and its affiliates disclaim any liability for any damages caused by use of this software or hardware in dangerous applications.

Third-Party Content, Products, and Services Disclaimer
This software or hardware and documentation may provide access to or information on content, products, and services from third parties. Oracle Corporation and its affiliates are not responsible for and expressly disclaim all warranties of any kind with respect to third-party content, products, and services. Oracle Corporation and its affiliates will not be responsible for any loss, costs, or damages incurred due to your access to or use of third-party content, products, or services.

Alpha and Beta Draft Documentation Notice
If this document is in prerelease status:

This documentation is in prerelease status and is intended for demonstration and preliminary use only. It may not be specific to the hardware on which you are using the software. Oracle Corporation and its affiliates are not responsible for and expressly disclaim all warranties of any kind with respect to this documentation and will not be responsible for any loss, costs, or damages incurred due to the use of this documentation.

Oracle Logo

Cookie PreferencesAd Choices

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).